# Lightweight Revision Control for copying config files from a testing server to production server

Tags: amazon-ec2, git, version-control

I am working with EC2, and trying to set up a good system so that I can launch an instance, make changes to a few files (e.g. init scripts), and copy those changes over to the production server, with the ability to roll back changes.

I found this [old thread](https://serverfault.com/questions/5410/using-revision-control-for-server-configuration-files) very helpful and am thinking of putting the server's root under a git repository and adding the few files I'll be modifying under version control per [this tutorial](http://jottit.com/jg8h7/), but that seems a bit overkill, and I also want to make sure I'm not overlooking some better method for testing and copying over changes.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We use Subversion for doing exactly that, and trust me - it's not overkill. Not at all. Especially when two people check in different versions of the same INI and you see that beautiful "Changes Merged" message, which means you both get to keep your changes... There are even free hosted SVN (and GIT) providers if you can share the one login for everyone.

If you just want version control for the server-side config files, try a program called [FileHamster](http://www.filehamster.com/). It used to be free (don't know if it still is). It's like a local version control system. It will watch whatever folder you ask it to and keep revisions of each change, which you can then roll back.

Because it's single user, you don't get merging, and you're on your own for transferring the config files.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It's good to know more people are doing this.