# Linux: how to restore config file using apt-get/aptitude?

Tags: linux, configuration, apt, restore, dependencies

I've occasionally lost my config file "/etc/mysql/my.cnf", and want to restore it. The file belongs to package `mysql-common` which is needed for some vital functionality so I can't just `purge && install` it: the dependencies would be also uninstalled (or if I can ignore them temporarily, they won't be working).

Is there a way to restore the config file from a package without un-`ar`-ing the package file?

`dpkg-reconfigure mysql-common` did not restore it.

Comment: i've always just extracted the package files with 7zip (`7z x /path/to/foo.deb`, then `7z x data.tar.gz`)....

Comment: Personally, I like to setup something like etckeeper on my system right after I install.  That way all changes and versions of configuration files get stored.  (http://serverfault.com/questions/13091/advice-on-storing-etc-in-a-vcs)

Comment: And this, kids, is why we have *backups*...

Comment: @womble: actually, the situation is slightly different: i have a config file, but it's modified by me. I was not using `conf.d` folders, and when the package maintainer update it, upgrade process becomes really keen of displaying "config file modified" messages :) The reason is not that important to mention, so I decided to simplify my question

Answer (score 39, accepted):

`dpkg -i --force-confmiss mysql-common.deb` will recreate any missing configuration files, ie `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` in your case.

Comment: Thanks! On Ubuntu, it was `sudo dpkg --force-confmiss -i /var/cache/apt/archives/mysql-common*.deb`

Comment: Hi, Would this work for `mysql-apt-config` as well. My `mysql-apt-config` is missing. Thanks Michael

Answer (score 18):

None of the above worked for me - maybe outdated - anyway, I found this solution:

```
apt-get -o Dpkg::Options::="--force-confmiss" install --reinstall mysql-common
```

Comment: This is the command to use, considering aptitude  is not default. Don't forget the sudo :)

Answer (score 10):

In Debian Squeeze — at least —, we also can do it this way, after `su` — or `sudo` for Ubuntu —

```
aptitude install -o Dpkg::Options::=--force-confmiss mysql-server
```

This will care for the dependencies of `mysql-server` and reset all the missing conf files of the lot, including `mysql-common`. Conflicting (remaining) files will be prompted out to be kept or reset.

Unfortunately, there is [a bug in aptitude](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/aptitude/+bug/234184), and

```
aptitude purge -o Dpkg::Options::=--force-all mysql-server
```

**will not work**.
So we have to do it one by one with

```
dpkg --force-all --purge  mysql-common  mysql-server  mysql-client …
```

This will **remove any config file**, original or modified, **but custom files** will be preserved, with an onscreen message.
Note, by the way, that `dpkg` also recognizes `--force-confnew` and `--force-confold` options.

To get `mysql-server` dependencies' list print on screen :

```
aptitude --simulate remove mysql-server
```

Answer (score 3):

You can find default mysql config files in `/usr/share/doc/mysql-server-5.0/examples/` or similar. That may be all that you need unless you have some really special/esoteric configurations enabled.

Answer (score 0):

In my `/etc/mysql/` directory, I have a `my.cnf.orig` file which contains the original contents of `my.cnf`.

I'm not sure where `/etc/mysql/my.cnf.orig` came from - that is, whether **I** created it, or the installation of mysql did it. I remember checking at one time that it *was* exactly the same as `my.cnf`

If you have such a thing, and **no** `my.cnf` you can copy one to the other.

```
sudo cp /etc/mysql/my.cnf.orig /etc/mysql/my.cnf
```

In any case, it's a simple text file of 3897 bytes and you could copy and paste from a generic Mysql configuration file.

It will be a good idea *once you restore* your `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` to make a copy so you can restore it easily in future.

Comment: I usually make a backup of original-install configuration files by copying them to `/path/to/foo.conf.orig` ... if these are automatically installed, they're created when apt-get is installing a new version and detects you've altered the original configuration file.

Comment: Hmm, the more I think about it, the more it seems **I** created `/etc/mysql/my.cnf.orig` as a backup which wouldn't be overwritten by a fresh installation. But, putting it somewhere entirely different is a good idea.

Comment: I was trying to be generic; for my.cnf I would copy it to `/etc/mysql/my.cnf.orig`.  Then, naturally, make a tarball backup of `/etc`.  :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to reinstall mysql-common with this command:`apt-get install --reinstall mysql-common`

Comment: Does that actually restore missing configuration files?

Comment: No, that doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

It appears some of the other solutions won't work [if the configuration files of the package are managed](https://lists.debian.org/debian-user/2012/03/msg00807.html) with `ucf`.

In this case you can use :

```
UCF_FORCE_CONFFMISS=1 apt-get --reinstall install [pkgname]
```