# Can't open /usr/lib/ssl/openssl.cnf

Tags: ssl, openssl

Create key and certificate:

```
openssl req -x509 -nodes -days 365 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout /etc/apache2/ssl/apache.key -out /etc/apache2/ssl/apache.crt
Can't open /usr/lib/ssl/openssl.cnf for reading, No such file or directory
140713226073408:error:02001002:system library:fopen:No such file or directory:../crypto/bio/bss_file.c:69:fopen('/usr/lib/ssl/openssl.cnf','r')
140713226073408:error:2006D080:BIO routines:BIO_new_file:no such file:../crypto/bio/bss_file.c:76:
```

Reinstall it with:

```
apt install openssl --reinstall
```

Check the file with:

```
ls -al  /usr/lib/ssl/openssl.cnf
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 20 Mar 19 02:25 /usr/lib/ssl/openssl.cnf -> /etc/ssl/openssl.cnf
ls -al /etc/ssl/openssl.cnf
ls: cannot access '/etc/ssl/openssl.cnf': No such file or directory
```

How can solve the issue then?

Comment: https://serverfault.com/questions/82801/linux-how-to-restore-config-file-using-apt-get-aptitude , https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/277193/how-to-reinstall-configuration-file , https://askubuntu.com/questions/66533/how-can-i-restore-configuration-files

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Download the file from https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/master/apps/openssl.cnf, maybe changing the branch to suit your version (as retrieved with `openssl version`).

Save it as `/etc/ssl/openssl.cnf`.

Alternatively, you could search your system for the file with:

```
find / -iname openssl.cnf
```

If you are lucky enough to find it, many of the `openssl` commands accept the `-config` option to point to an alternative file; or you could simply move it to it's correct home.

Answer (score 2):

You can find the openssl.cnf path like this

$ openssl version -d

OPENSSLDIR: "/etc/pki/tls"

Answer (score 0):

1. url address

The url should be  `https://raw.githubusercontent.com/openssl/openssl/master/apps/openssl.cnf`.

2. target directory

It should be `/usr/lib/ssl/openssl.cnf` instead of `/etc/ssl/openssl.cnf`.

```
curl -k  https://raw.githubusercontent.com/openssl/openssl/master/apps/openssl.cnf       
-o  /usr/lib/ssl/openssl.cnf
```